# How to config instance messaging for asterisk 12

Tags: asterisk, messaging, pjsip, freepbx

I am using the asterisk 12 with pjsip, I wonder how could I config the instance meesseging for pjsqip in asterisk 12 ? What is the default message context for pjssip ? I use the default extension.conf from the installation and I successfully could make the call over each but when I try to send message, it does not receive by the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `message_context` in the endpoint definition of pjsip.conf.

By default messaging context is the same as `context`.

Comment: my pjsip.conf is the auto_generated file from freepbx and it should not be modified. I really cannot find where to set the messge_context in freepbx UI at all. could you please show me where?

Comment: It depends on how many users have to have this context. If not much, then you can copy the sections with this users from pjsip.endpoint.conf into pjsip.endpoint_custom.conf and add message_context to each section.

Comment: freepbx ui not support messaging, so you have use pjsip_custom.conf and extensions_custom.conf